# How to restrict changing desktop wallpaper?

Tags: macos, parental-controls

We have Macbook Airs running 10.8.1. These are exposed to students in a k-12 setting. I'd like to restrict their ability to change the wallpaper of the desktop.  Is there a setting to configure?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any way to prevent changing the desktop picture, but you could just change it back to the default every few seconds.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST
1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.stackexchange.apple.65938</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>osascript</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>tell application "Finder"
set f to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Galaxy.jpg"
if desktop picture is not file f then set desktop picture to f
end tell</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Save the file above as `/Library/LaunchAgents/com.stackexchange.apple.65938.plist`, change the owner, and load the plist:

```
sudo chown root /Library/LaunchAgents/com.stackexchange.apple.65938.plist
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.stackexchange.apple.65938.plist
```

The property list is loaded automatically when users log in.

Comment: I have just started getting an error when I type in `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.stackexchange.apple.65938.plist` I get `launchctl: Dubious permissions on file (skipping): /Library/LaunchAgents/com.stackexchange.apple.65938.plist
nothing found to load` Any suggestion on where to start looking for for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal, the following:

```
chown (USER)
/Users/(USER)/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist
```

Where `(USER)` is the short user name.

Then, lock that file:

```
chflags uchg /Users/(USER)/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist
```

Comment: Can you specify which shortname to use for the (USER) variables?  I have an admin account and a student. When I enter:     chown admin
/Users/student/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist  It says permission denied.

Comment: Isn't it owned by the user by default? Anyway `chflags uchg` didn't work for me. The desktop picture is changed before the plist is modified.

Comment: This doesn't work with Safari option "set image as background"