# osascript to set secondary desktop background?

Tags: applescript, display, desktop

I have been using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST
1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.filmscoring.display.plist</string>
 <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>osascript</string>
    <string>-e</string>
    <string>tell application "Finder"
set f to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/mac cinema desktop yoda.png"
if desktop picture is not file f then set desktop picture to f
end tell</string>
  </array>
 <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>10</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

To prevent users from changing the desktop. (And I love it btw!) Original can be found here: [How to restrict changing desktop wallpaper?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65938/how-to-restrict-changing-desktop-wallpaper)

All of our stations have a secondary screen which I'd also like to fix up the same way using a different image.

Any idea how I can target the secondary display with this code? Thanks for the help!

Comment: System Events has a desktop suite. (In Applescript Editor, File > Open Dictionary > System Events.app, then click Desktop Suite on the left column) When I try to use it to get the picture property of one of them, I get "invalid key form" errors. This might be something only happening on my system, though, so it's probably worth trying. (update:it just started working)

Also, it would help to know your version of OS X.

Answer (score 2):

Quick Google search revealed the following code:

```
set tlst to {}
--set newtop to (path to home folder as string) & "Pictures:desktop pics folder:BigDipper 916.jpg" as alias -- sample line
set newtop to choose file


tell application "System Events"
   set tlst to a reference to every desktop
   --set picture of item 1 of tlst to newtop -- display 1
   set picture of item 2 of tlst to newtop -- display 2
end tell
```

Taken from

http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=35840

I don't have a second monitor so I cannot test it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Works on macOS Big Sur**

For the Default monitor

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set picture of current desktop to "<path-to-img>"'
```

For the second monitor

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set picture of second desktop to "<path-to-img>"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following (based on the answer from @Vic)

```
    tell application "System Events"
        set tlst to a reference to every desktop
        set picture of item 2 of tlst to "/Users/jason/Documents/Personal/Me/moon.png"
    end tell
```

I can verify that it does work with a two monitor setup (MacBookPro and external monitor)